# lang:go & vs-code: how to get a duplicate name warning

Tags: go, warnings, vscode-extensions

My mistake:

```golang
var x int
if ... {
    x := 5 // <-- accidantly written ":=" instead of "="
    fmt.Println( x )
}
... // use x then
```

This compiles fine. Is there a way to get a warning from vscode or an other tool? BTW: Somtimes a warning about similar `MyName` and `myName` could be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the tool could detect the `variable shadowing`. You could try `go vet` as below

The 'shadow' analyzer can be built and run using these commands:

```
  go install golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/shadow/cmd/shadow
  go vet -vettool=$(which shadow)
```

---

Another option is config `go vet` in [golangci-lint](https://golangci-lint.run/usage/linters/)

Enable `check-shadowing` on `.golangci.yml`

```
linters-settings:
  govet:
    check-shadowing: true
```

File t.go

```golang
func main() {
    a := 1
    if true {
        a := 2
        fmt.Println(a)
    }
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Then run `golangci-lint run ./t.go` and got

```
t.go:8:3: shadow: declaration of "a" shadows declaration at line 6 (govet)
                a := 2
                ^
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/i8ch3t/is_there_a_tool_that_warns_about_variable/) and it shows a warning during editing.
Adding to `./MyProject/.vscode/settings.json`:

```json
    "gopls": {
        "ui.diagnostic.analyses": {
            "shadow": true
        },
    },
```

Editing the **user** `settings.json` file on your machine gives the editor warning for all local projects.